# How to make Firebase ".info/connected" and .onDisconnect() accurate with each other?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make user presence with ".info/connected" and .onDisconnect() in FireBase, I'm making a chatroom of sorts. The issue I've come across is that if a user turns off their wifi/data and then exits the app, onDisconnect() does not trigger which is crucial for the functioning of the chat rooms otherwise 2 instances of the same user could show up in one chatroom. I would like to implement it so that onDisconnect() triggers when ".info/connected" triggers as it seems they go at completely different times. How would I go about this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    

    // References
    private User user;
    private Room room;
    private String userKey;

    // Database References
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference referenceUser, referenceUserStatus, referenceUserRoom, referenceRooms, referenceUserSlot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        hideSystemUI();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        userKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("userKey");
        Log.e("USER KEY: ", userKey);
        user = new User();
        user.setUserKey(userKey);

        // Database References
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        referenceUser = database.getReference("Users/"+user.getUserKey());
        referenceUserStatus = database.getReference("Users/"+user.getUserKey()+"/userStatus/");
        referenceRooms = database.getReference("Rooms");

            // Create Initial User
            referenceUser.setValue(user);
            referenceUserStatus.onDisconnect().setValue("OFFLINE");






        checkConnectionStatus();


    }

    private void searchForRooms(){

        final ProgressBar progressBarRoom = findViewById(R.id.progressBarRoom);
        final TextView textFindingRoom = findViewById(R.id.textSearchingForRoom);
        progressBarRoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textFindingRoom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if(referenceUserSlot!= null) {
            referenceUserSlot.setValue("");
        }

        user.setUserSlot("");
        user.setUserRoomKey("");
        user.setUserStatus("ONLINE");
        referenceUser.setValue(user);

        referenceRooms.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Room roomFromList = dataSnapshot.getValue(Room.class);

                    int emptySlot = roomFromList.getEmptySlot();
                        if(emptySlot != 0 /* 0 means no empty slots */){

                            // Assign  room key to user
                            user.setUserRoomKey(roomFromList.getRoomKey());
                            user.setUserSlot("slot"+Integer.toString(emptySlot));

                            referenceUser.setValue(user);

                            // Assign User's key to slot
                            roomFromList.setSlotKey(user.getUserKey(), emptySlot);

                            // Set new value of room slot
                            dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(roomFromList);

                            // MAKE SURE TO UPDATE REFERENCES SO USER HAS ACCURATE POINTERS TO DATABASE
                            updateDatabaseReferences();

                            // Make searching frame invisible
                            progressBarRoom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            textFindingRoom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                            break;
                        }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });



    }

    private void checkConnectionStatus(){
        DatabaseReference referenceConnection = database.getReference(".info/connected");
        referenceConnection.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                boolean isConnected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);

                if(isConnected){
                        Log.e("CONNECTION", "REGAINED");
                        searchForRooms();
                }
                else{
                   // TRIGGERS ON STARTUP FOR SOME REASON?
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void updateDatabaseReferences(){

        referenceUserRoom = database.getReference("Rooms/"+user.getUserRoomKey());
        referenceUserSlot = database.getReference("Rooms/"+user.getUserRoomKey()+"/"+user.getUserSlot());

        referenceUserSlot.onDisconnect().setValue("");


    }

    public void hideSystemUI(){
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

Comment: `onDisconnect` may take a few minutes to fire, as it depends on the socket timing out on the server. Since `.info/connect` is client-side, it typically detects the disconnect much faster than that. If you need something else, you might want to implement a keep-alive/last-seen message system.

Comment: Well I have a device in which i turn off the wifi and data, and then close the app. I wait for minutes and nothing happens from the onDisconnect(). Is this just a bug?

Comment: 1) "nothing happens" is hard to help with. What did you expect to happen? How did you check? How long did you wait? 2) In general this `referenceUserStatus.onDisconnect().setValue("OFFLINE")` looks not ideal, as a single user can easily end up with multiple connections on a single device (for example: when there's a network glitch/change). That's why the example in the documentation uses a new push key for each connection: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample

Comment: Well it actually looks like it takes around 10 minutes for my data to disappear with that function, less than ideal since I want users to be able to drop in and out. I'll look into this example and study it thank you!

Comment: Good to hear that they disappear after a while. 10 minutes indeed does sound longer than I'm used to, but it they disappear you are definitely just waiting for the socket to disconnect/timewait.